# How to run a copy script after every build in CMAKE and CLION?

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I am trying to copy a directory of files after my project is built, *every* time my project is built.

In my project's `CMakeLists.txt` file I have the following:

```
# Copy resources
file(COPY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/assets DESTINATION ${PROJECT_BUILD_DIR}/)
```

This works the first time the project is built, and it works anytime I call `make` in the directory that CMAKE has generated the makefile in.

However, in my IDE (CLion) I think there is some sort of caching / checking to see if the project is already built.

As a result, if I only change an asset file, and not the underlying code, the files are never copied to the location of the binary.

Is there a way to force a post-build script to be executed after *every* time build is called?

Or, put another way, is there a way to force the `CMakeLists.txt` file to be **every** time I build my project?

This is specific to CLion but concerns cmake more generally.

I am using CMAKE `3.9.1`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File(COPY file path) is executed at configure time, one of the three main phase of CMake flow Configure -> build -> install

If you want to execute a command after a build there is two ways to do it.

First with (Probably the better one)

```
add_custom_command(TARGET MyTarget POST_BUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/assets $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:MyTarget>/assets)
```

Will copy the asset directory, to artifactDirectory/assets.
You need to precise the assets directory in the destination.
CMake documentation isn't that clear on this point

> copy_directory ... 
>       Copy directories to  directory. If  directory does not exist it will be created.

Reference is there : [add_custom_command (3.9.6)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/add_custom_command.html)

Second with a custom target that execute at the end of the build of every targets  and so depends on all targets.

Syntax would be

```
add_custom_target( MyTarget ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/assets $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:MyTarget>/assets DEPENDS MyOtherTargets)`
```

Will create a target called MyTarget that execute, a command when builded after target or files it depends on are builded/generated.

(This command have some unexpected behaviours when a project is built, with multiple cores.)

Reference is there :  [add_custom_target (3.9.6)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/add_custom_target.html)

For information my environment is CLION 2017.3 and CMake 3.10

Comment: In your answer you do not say how to copy files.  I tried: `add_custom_command(TARGET MyTarget PRE_BUILD
                   COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory
                       ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/assets $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:MyTarget>)` but I had the same issue.  It looks like my IDE is caching the results of the build. i.e. something like message("this ran") is not even printed.

Comment: PRE BUILD will be copied before build not after . 
I ll try to improve my answer when I ll be on my computer with CLIOn

Comment: I updated my answer, tell me if it's solve your problem.

Comment: This is a better way to do it. *Note:* The real trick was making sure I ran `clean` from CLion in between builds.

Comment: Yeah but, it's just a workaround, you should be able to run it without running clean. Like checking new files in assets and copy at the right time.